# Flink job production readiness - validate UUIDs assigned to all operators

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The flink production readiness (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/production_ready.html) suggests assigning UUIDs to all operators. I'm looking for a way to validate that all operators in a given job graph have been assigned UUIDs -- ideally to be used as a pre-deployment check in our CI flow.

We already have a process in place that uses the `PackagedProgram` class to get a JSON-formatted 'preview plan'. Unfortunately, that does not include any information about the assigned UUIDs (or lack thereof).

Digging into the code behind generating the JSON preview plan (`PlanJSONDumpGenerator`), I can trace how it visits each of the nodes as a `DumpableNode<?>`, but from there, I can't find anything that leads me to the definition of the operator with it's UUID.

When defining the job (using the DataStream API), the UUID is assigned on a `StreamTransformation<T>`. Is there anyway to connect the data in the `PackagedProgram` back to the original `StreamTransformation<T>`s to get the UUID?

Or is there a better approach to doing this type of validation?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you’ll want to explicitly setting the UID values for all of the operators in your job to ensure they can be properly restored and support potential changes to the graph.

You can use the [`disableAutoGeneratedUIDs()`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/ExecutionConfig.html#enableAutoGeneratedUIDs) for the job to enforce and validate that all of the operators for the job have these set:

```
yourStream
    .getConfig()
    .disableAutoGeneratedUIDs()
```

This is a recommended configuration for all production-ready Flink jobs, as any graph changes when using autogenerated UID values can result in previous state being discarded or potential incorrect restoration of existing state against a different operator.